# Open angular 4 application on browser (Chrome) other than the default browser (IE) when link clicked from mail

Tags: angular

I want my Angular 4 application to open on Chrome instead of the default browser that is IE when user clicks on a link from their email without hampering REDIRECTION. So a login page should open and only after successful login, the user should be redirected to intended page.

Using the below piece of code I am able to determine the browser that the link has opened on. If the browser is anything other than Chrome then I am asking the user to open the application on Chrome. But because he has access to the login URL only, even when he successfully logs in, he won't be redirected to the intended page.

`this.isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);`

User clicks on https://localhost:4200/#/qm/request and the login page opens correctly on IE whose URL is https://localhost:4200/#/qm/login.

Since the user is alerted to open the application on Chrome, he copy pastes this login URL instead of the request URL and therefore failing the redirection.

What I want to do is when the user clicks on the link from his email, the application should directly open on Chrome instead of his default browser. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I think for that you would need to change your default browser in Default apps settings of windows. Could you try that?

Comment: I have over 100 clients who would be using this system. Changing the default settings of all these clients wouldn't be feasible. Yes, this is Plan B, but I would like to avoid this situation. Is there any Angular configuration that I could change to force the application to open on Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking if you can provide a "Copy Link" button (which contains the actual mail link not login) on the page itself (after you detect its an IE Browser), so that user will click button to copy link instead of copying it from address bar....